# Using Times in a Factor to Create a Custom Column

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I have a dataset titled **`nypd`**, which has a column titled **`OCCUR_TIME`**. This column contains various times `(ex: 3:57:00, 10:31:00, 22:15:00, etc.)`.

I would like to create a custom **`TIME_OF_DAY`** column using R; I wrote this code below:

```
nypd$TIME_OF_DAY <- 'Night'
nypd[nypd$OCCUR_TIME >=  6:00:00 & nypd$OCCUR_TIME < 12:00:00,] <- 'Morning'
nypd[nypd$OCCUR_TIME >= 12:00:00 & nypd$OCCUR_TIME < 16:00:00,] <- 'Afternoon'
nypd[nypd$OCCUR_TIME >= 16:00:00 & nypd$OCCUR_TIME < 20:00:00,] <- 'Evening'
```

The error I am getting is *`` Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, nypd$OCCUR_TIME >= "6:00:00" & nypd$OCCUR_TIME < : missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames ``*.

I'm new to R so I am not too familiar with the error codes, but I'm thinking the error is due to my values in the **`OCCUR_TIME`** column not being read as a "time" type of value, so I can't use any operators.

Could someone please help me figure out where I'm going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: you should look up how dates and times are represented in R.  Try `help(DateTimeClasses)`

Comment: It looks like you are using [open data from nyc](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Public-Safety/NYPD-Shooting-Incident-Data-Year-To-Date-/5ucz-vwe8) - you should include instructions of how to obtain that data in your question. Is it maybe included in a package? Also your lines 2 to 4 don't specify the column you want to write to.

Answer (score 1):

First, as the error is saying, you have missing values in your data. Since we don't have your data to work with, let's make up some data to use:

```
> data(iris)
> iris$Petal.Length[3:5] <- NA
> head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2           NA         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1           NA         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6           NA         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Now, it has a problem with subsetting on `Petal.Length` because it isn't sure what to do when there are missing values.

```
> iris[iris$Petal.Length > 1.2 & iris$Petal.Length < 1.5, ] <- 50
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, iris$Petal.Length > 1.2 & iris$Petal.Length <  : 
                            missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
```

Also note that when you do this:

```
nypd[nypd$OCCUR_TIME >=  6:00:00 & nypd$OCCUR_TIME < 12:00:00,] <- 'Morning'
```

You aren't telling it what variable you want to assign `'Morning'` to!

You can add a test for `is.na` to your boolean, and include the variable name you want to affect:

```
> iris[!is.na(iris$Petal.Length) & iris$Petal.Length > 1.2 & iris$Petal.Length < 1.5, 'Petal.Length'] <- 50
> head(iris)                              
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5         50.0         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0         50.0         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2           NA         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1           NA         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6           NA         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

The advice about learning how to deal with dates and times in R is true, the way you are expressing them here is not right. If they are being read in as a factor, then perhaps however you are reading your data you need to add a `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`?

Comment: When I use na.omit, I get a different error:

```numerical expression has 7 elements: only the first used�>=� not meaningful for factors```

this error actually repeats itself a few times, with a different # of elements each time.

Based off of my very limited knowledge of R, it sounds like I cant use operators with factors?

Comment: Apologies, that `na.omit` part wasn't correct. I'll try to come back to this if I have time later.

Answer (score 0):

We could convert the 'OCCUR_TIME' to Time class with `as.ITime` from `data.table`, then do the the comparison

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
nypd %>%
    mutate(OCCUR_TIME = as.ITime(OCCUR_TIME),
           TIME_OF_DAY = case_when(between(OCCUR_TIME, as.ITime("06:00:00"),
               as.ITime("12:00:00")) ~ "Morning",
            between(OCCUR_TIME, as.ITime("12:00:00"),
               as.ITime("16:00:00")) ~ "Afternoon",
            between(OCCUR_TIME, as.ITime("16:00:00"),
               as.ITime("20:00:00")) ~ "Evening", TRUE ~ "Night"))
#  OCCUR_TIME TIME_OF_DAY
#1   05:22:34       Night
#2   07:22:29     Morning
#3   12:20:05   Afternoon
#4   15:46:23   Afternoon
#5   19:32:42     Evening
```

#### data

```
nypd <- data.frame(OCCUR_TIME = c("05:22:34", "07:22:29", "12:20:05",
     "15:46:23", "19:32:42"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your response, I'll definitely give it a shot. Have to figure out all the components of your code first!